# How to notify new data added in stream in flutter

Tags: flutter, firebase-realtime-database, stream-builder

*My code is working fine whenever new data is added to the database it appears to my screen without refreshing page what I want is it will print a message as well that a new data is added so that I can even trigger any sound as well to notify user that a new data is added.*

***I've tried one approach by counting number of items in List and then tracking if it gets increased by one then shoot the message, but that didn't work.***

***This is my code:***

````
                        stream: FirebaseDatabase.instance.reference().child('PendingOrders').child('78945615').onValue,
                        builder: (context, snapshot){
                            if(snapshot.hasData && !snapshot.hasError && snapshot.data.snapshot.value!=null) {
                              DataSnapshot snapshot1 = snapshot.data.snapshot;
                              List<
                                  PendingOrderLoader> pendingOrderLoaderList = [
                              ];
                              int counter = 0;

                              final key = snapshot1.value.keys;
                              for (var i in key) {
                                PendingOrderLoader pendingOrderLoader1 = new PendingOrderLoader(
                                    snapshot1.value[i]['ContactNumber'],
                                    snapshot1.value[i]['TotalPrice'],
                                    snapshot1.value[i]['Date'],
                                    snapshot1.value[i]['Time'],
                                    snapshot1.value[i]['Address']['Line1'],
                                    snapshot1.value[i]['Address']['Line2'],

                                );
                                pendingOrderLoaderList.add(pendingOrderLoader1);
                                pendingOrderLoaderList.sort((a, b) =>
                                    a.Counter.compareTo(b.Counter));
                                counter = counter+1;
                              }
                              return
                                snapshot.data.snapshot.value == null
                                  ? SizedBox()

                                  :
                              ListView.builder
                                (
                                  shrinkWrap: true,
                                  scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                                  itemCount: pendingOrderLoaderList.length,
                                  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                                    return pendingOrderLoaderList.length == 0
                                        ? Container(
                                      child: Text("No Pending Items"),)
                                        : Padding(
                                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                                      child: InkWell(
                                        onTap: () {

                                          Navigator.push(
                                              context, MaterialPageRoute(
                                              builder: (context) =>
                                                  PendingOrderDetails(
                                                      orderID: pendingOrderLoaderList[index]
                                                          .OrderID,
                                                      totalPrice: pendingOrderLoaderList[index]
                                                          .TotalPrice,
                                                      contactNumber: pendingOrderLoaderList[index]
                                                          .ContactNumber,
                                                      line1: pendingOrderLoaderList[index]
                                                          .Line1,
                                                      line2: pendingOrderLoaderList[index]
                                                          .Line2,
                                                      Date: pendingOrderLoaderList[index]
                                                          .Date,
                                                      Time: pendingOrderLoaderList[index]
                                                          .Time,
                                                      PaymentMethod: pendingOrderLoaderList[index]
                                                          .PaymentMethod,
                                                  )
                                          ));
                                        },
                                        child: Column(
                                          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment
                                              .start,
                                          children: <Widget>[
                                            Container(
                                                margin: EdgeInsets.only(
                                                    left: 10, top: 10),
                                                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                                    borderRadius: BorderRadius
                                                        .circular(10),
                                                    color: Colors.cyan),
                                                child: Padding(
                                                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(
                                                      8.0),
                                                  child: Column(
                                                    children: <Widget>[
                                                      Row(
                                                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment
                                                            .spaceEvenly,
                                                        children: <Widget>[
                                                          Text(
                                                              (pendingOrderLoaderList[index]
                                                                  .Counter)
                                                                  .toString()),
                                                          Text(
                                                              pendingOrderLoaderList[index]
                                                                  .PaymentMethod),
                                                          Text(
                                                              pendingOrderLoaderList[index]
                                                                  .OrderID),
                                                          Text(
                                                              pendingOrderLoaderList[index]
                                                                  .Time),
                                                        ],
                                                      ),

                                                    ],
                                                  ),
                                                )
                                            ),

                                          ],

                                        ),
                                      ),
                                    );
                                  }
                              );
                            }else{
                              return   Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator()
                            );
                            }


                        })```
````

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use ConnectionState for this. Check your snapshot's connectionState.If this turns 'done' to 'active', that means something added.

Comment: Hey @Emin,If you don't mind can you please add a small snippet of code?

Comment: When there is data in the list then it always shows active, I want only to trigger when new data is added.

Comment: Actually i just realized that it is not working but streambuilder refresh itself when something added to database. So if i understand your question right , you can just give your warning before  your streamBuilder hasn't return the ListView.Builder().

Comment: Actually what I want, when new data is added to list it will pop print statement saying new data is added.

Comment: Whenever I'm adding new data it appears to the screen automatically but I want to trigger that new data as it appears on the screen through any message or tone.

Comment: Hmm so i think you need to add these datas to database with their adding time, then you can use the latest added data.

Comment: That is not I wanted to ask I'm able to get the latest data, I've used counter for that what I want is when new data appear on screen it will notify the user that one new data is added same as whatsapp when you've already open a chat window and a new message appears, it appeared with sound.

Comment: And don't think of it as notification I don't want that. Message will only appear when that screen is already opened.

Comment: Actually i don't understand your problem but if you are asking for like  a chat app feature i used to do something like that. When a message added to messageRoom's collections , i updated to messageRoom 's "last_message"  and "isSeen" fields. Then last added or unreaded messages can have some features or can be using in app. If your problem is kind of this you can use something like that

Answer (score 0):

just check length of fetched data and make a alert(or a sound)

```js
Stream<List<MESSAGELIST>> chatStream() async* {
    while (true) {
      await Future.delayed(Duration(milliseconds: 500));
      List<MESSAGELIST> someChat = await getMessageList(bid);
      if(someChat.length > dataLength) {  setState(() {
        sound.play('ding.mp3');
        createChatNotifications();
        dataLength = someChat.length;
      });}
      yield someChat;
    }
  }
```